# Как проверить порядок массива

Tags: php

Есть массив

```
$order = [1,2,3];
```

Это главный массив, по нему нужно сделать проверку порядка другого массива.

И массив в котором нужно проверить порядок

```
$test = [
  0 => [
    'id' => 1
  ],
  1 => [
    'id' => 3
  ],
];
```

Получается нужно узнать, идут ли `id` второго массива по порядку первого массива

Если порядок первого массива `1,2,3`, а второго `1,3` - То это правильный порядок

Если порядок первого массива `1,2,3`, а второго `2,3` - То это правильный порядок

Если порядок первого массива `1,2,3`, а второго `1,2,3` - То это правильный порядок

Если порядок первого массива `1,2,3`, а второго `3,2` - То это не правильный порядок

С чего начать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$check = function($data) use ($order){
            foreach($data as $v){
                $p = array_search($v, $order);
                if($p === false) return false;
                $order = array_slice($order, $p);
            }
            return true;
         };
```

можно как-то так искать, хотя хочется поизящнее (например как-то с `array_shift($oder)`). Берете элемент `data`, ищите его в `order`, если нашлось, обрезаете `order` до этой найденной позиции, и идете дальше. А если не нашлось,то не соответствует.

---

*дополнено:

что-то вроде такого (тело предыдущей функции), но что-то я не уверен, что оно работает корректно.*

```
 foreach($data as $v){
     while( $order && $v != ($o = array_shift($order)));
     if( $v !== $o ) return false;
 }
 return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function f($a, $b) {
    $n = 0;
    $a_count = count($a);

    for ($i = 0, $k = count($b); $i < $k; $i++) {
        while($n <= $a_count){
            if ($b[$i]['id'] == $a[$n]) {
                break;
            }else{
                if($n == $a_count){
                    return false;
                }
                $n++;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}


$order = [1,2,3];

$test = [
  0 => [
    'id' => 1
  ],
  1 => [
    'id' => 3
  ],
];
$test2 = [
  0 => [
    'id' => 3
  ],
  1 => [
    'id' => 2
  ],
];
$test3 = [
  0 => [
    'id' => 1
  ],
  1 => [
    'id' => 2
  ],
];
$test4 = [
  0 => [
    'id' => 2
  ],
  1 => [
    'id' => 3
  ],
];
$test5 = [
  0 => [
    'id' => 3
  ],
  1 => [
    'id' => 1
  ],
];
$test6 = [
  0 => [
    'id' => 2
  ],
  1 => [
    'id' => 1
  ],
];


echo '1(13)['.f($order, $test).']<br/>'.
'2(32)['.f($order, $test2).']<br/>'.
'3(12)['.f($order, $test3).']<br/>'.
'4(23)['.f($order, $test4).']<br/>'.
'5(31)['.f($order, $test5).']<br/>'.
'6(21)['.f($order, $test6).']<br/>';
```

Выведет:
1(13)[1]
2(32)[]
3(12)[1]
4(23)[1]
5(31)[]
6(21)[]

Comment: Вылазит ошибка при не верном порядке `Undefined offset` в строке `if ($b[$i]['id'] == $a[$n]) {`  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/252fa32838966d279aa988aacf021953ae1f82d5